# How to create .wsp file manually for sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

i designed one webpart using open xml sdk, how to create .wsp file manually without using vs2010.

Thanks in Advance,
Balaji

Answer (score 2):

You need to create all xml files manually an then packages them as cab file with wsp extension.
Please follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543741%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instruction from MSDN.